# How to pass a textbox value as a parameter to a controller method on selecting a item in autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a search textbox in my mvc application. By using Jquery Autocomplete like here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. Now I am able to display the suggestion list and when I select an item from that list submit method should call and the selected value will be appended to the textbox. I want to pass this appeded textbox value to a controller method for search.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchQuery", "Product", FormMethod.Get))
                        {
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="search-item">
                             @Html.TextBox("query", null, new { id = "SearchBox", @class = "SearchBox" ,placeholder="Search for item"})
                          <input type="submit" value="Search" data-icon="search" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true"  class="searchImg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      }
```

and jquery auto complete code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#SearchBox').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("Suggest", "Product")',
      minLength: 3,

  });

$("#SearchBox").on("autocompleteselect", function () { $.ajax("Product/SearchQuery/query=" $("#SearchBox").val()") });
```

but this is not working.

How can I get this? Please help me.

Comment: What you've tried? The question is unclear without seeing what you've tried and how!

Comment: what do you mean by append the selected value to the textbox after submit?? be bit clear

Comment: However When autocomplete changes a value, it fires a autocompletechange event(http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change), inside that event handler function you should place the code.

Comment: whatever the functionalty happening on submit button click that shoul be happen on selecting a item from autocomplete list without clicking submit button.